# Can't access abyss web server

Tags: webserver

I have installed abyss web server on my computer and I can access the the webserver in localhost. When I try to access the web server from another computer, typing my external ip I can't. What can I do? I've already tried to change the port from 80 to 8080 and to 8000, but it didn't work.

Comment: what OS are you running?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us much about you network setup but I think I can narrow this down to two likely problems. You either aren't forwarding your webserver port through your router correctly or you have a firewall blocking it. The easiest way to determine which it is is to disable any firewall you have running and try again. If that doesn't work then try from an internal IP.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without knowing the server, but there are two things you should look for:

- see if you can find a "bind address". It may be either `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`; change it to `0.0.0.0` and it will be listening to the outside world; and
- as krowe said, if by "another computer" you're talking about a computer in a different network, then you need to make sure you have the appropriate port forwards in place, and make sure you have no firewalls blocking it.

It may happen that these two scenarios are happening simultaneously. See if a computer in your network can access the server or not - if it can, the first scenario is not happening; if it can't, the first scenario is happening.